# Custom Class Not Drawing at Center - Swift

Tags: swift, uiview

I have a UIView with a custom class of TimerView. I am trying to draw a dot in the exact center of the UIView but it is appearing at the bottom slightly off center:

[image: UIView]

Custom class is here:

```
import UIKit

class TimerView: UIView {
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        drawDot()
    }

    func drawDot() {

        let midViewX = self.frame.midX
        let midViewY = self.frame.midY

        let dotPath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x: midViewX, y: midViewY, width: 5, height: 5))

        let dotLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        dotLayer.path = dotPath.cgPath
        dotLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor

        self.layer.addSublayer(dotLayer)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the re-implementation of `TimerView` class. For `UIView`, `init` is not the best place to get the `frame/bounds` values because it might change once the `autolayout` applies the constraints in runtime. `layoutSubviews` is the best place to get the correct `frame/bounds` values for parent/child views and to setup the child space properties. Secondly you should be using parent view `bounds` to setup the child's `frame`.

```
class TimerView: UIView {

    private var dotLayer: CAShapeLayer?

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        dotLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        dotLayer?.strokeColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        self.layer.addSublayer(dotLayer!)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        drawDot()
    }

    func drawDot() {

        let midViewX = self.bounds.midX
        let midViewY = self.bounds.midY

        let dotPath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x: midViewX, y: midViewY, width: 5, height: 5))
        dotLayer?.path = dotPath.cgPath
    }
}
```